# Flutter: How to authenticate api where the get request returns html

Tags: dart, flutter, httprequest, spotify

I'm trying to make an app in Flutter that uses the Spotify API. I specifically need to use the Spotify Web Api because it is the only one that allows access to the user's private playlists.

I'm trying to write code for the authentication but when I send the GET request, I get HTML in return.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
void _auth() async{
  final String state = randomAlphaNumeric(20);
  final Map<String, String> authQueryParameters = {
    "client_id": SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
    "response_type": "code",
    "redirect_uri": "painless_playlist://callback",
    "state": state,
    "scope": "playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-library-read"
  };
  Uri uri = new Uri.https(SPOTIFY_ACCOUNT_AUTHORITY, "authorize", authQueryParameters);
  print(uri.toString());
  HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.getUrl(uri);
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
  await response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).listen(print);
}
```

and this is what is returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" ng-app="accounts" ng-csp ng-strict-di>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title ng-bind="(&#39;loginTitle&#39; | localize) + &#39; - Spotify&#39;">Spotify</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://accounts.scdn.co/images/favicon.ace4d8543bbb017893402a1e9d1ac1fa.ico">
  <link href="https://accounts.scdn.co/css/index.2298e26e3e5796a7bb68.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">

  <script async defer
          src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit"
          nonce="wLHnpa4sDVHdmLiYTMXAZw=="></script>
  <script defer src="https://accounts.scdn.co/js/index.2298e26e3e5796a7bb68.js" sp-bootstrap></script>
  <meta ng-non-bindable sp-bootstrap-data='{"country":"US","captchaSiteKey":null,"useCaptcha":false,"BON":["0","0",1206798229]}'>
</head>
<body ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-include="template"></div>
</body>
</htm
```

I don't know what to do with this. Am I supposed to figure out how to open a browser and display this html? I've searched around and some resources say to open the uri in a browser instead of making a GET request, but that just shows an error page on Spotify's site.

I'm pretty lost at what to do; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont know how to solve your problem exectly but you have to display the HTML so that the user can login with his Spotify account

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code for Spotify API. It can also be used for other API calls. flutter_web_auth 0.1.2 package is used here.

```
void authenticate() async {
  // Present the dialog to the user
  final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
    url:
        "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=yourname:/&scope=user-read-currently-playing&response_type=token&state=123",
    callbackUrlScheme: "yourname",
  );

// Extract token from resulting url
  final token = Uri.parse(result);
  String at = token.fragment;
  at = "http://website/index.html?$at"; // Just for easy persing
  var accesstoken = Uri.parse(at).queryParameters['access_token'];
  print('token');
  print(accesstoken);
}
```

Add to AndroidManifest.xml  android\app\src\main

```
                 ...
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.linusu.flutter_web_auth.CallbackActivity" >
            <intent-filter android:label="flutter_web_auth">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="yourname" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pop open a browser so the user can login and authenticate with spotify thus allowing your app to access the spotify API.

In addition you'll probably need an API with an endpoint for Spotify to use as its 'callback' so you can process the authenticated user and get their AccessToken/RefreshToken to make future requests.

Your App will/should:

- call spotify to authorise (open browser in-app)
- user logs in
- spotify calls back to you API endpoint (you can then request the tokens from spotify and store them in your database)
- display a 'success' page/HTML in the app browser (this will be delivered by your api via the 'callback')
- you can now make requests to the spotify api using the tokens

Comment: can't we bypass the need for an API endpoint ? it is basically just a function away in my opinion

Comment: I might not know the full picture for flutter but I know that when a user logs in to Spotify they are sent back to a web based url with a code server-side. This code then needs to be exchanged for access/refresh tokens via a call to the Spotify api. Without this you can’t access Spotify on the users behalf. That’s where the web view comes in to play in my above solution.